# Migration of mysql table to DBF file 

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to import mysql table data to dbf (database foxpro) file using PHP..

I am utilizing the *dbase* functions to *dbase_create* to create database with the field names as same as in mysql table and added records of the mysql table using `dbase_add_record()` function..

Default datatype and length for "DATE" in dbf file is "D" and "8".

But imported dbf file shows that field type = "D" and field_length = "0".

Help to fix this problem thanks in advance

Comment: Please show your code, otherwise it's hard to tell where the error is.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should convert MYsql date to dbf date in php.

For example,

```
 $dbf_date = date('Ymd', strtotime($your_mysql_date));
```

Use $dbf_date during insert.

Comment: What Andre has is correct. The dbase date format is essentially the same as the MySQL format, except with the dashes removed. So you could also use: $dbf_date = str_replace("-", "", $your_mysql_date).